# jQuery Load() not forming to DIV

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-load

Hey all i am having some problems with loading an HTML page using jQuery's load() function within my div. If i have content inside my HTML page thats **larger (larger height)** than the DIV its going into originally then it just bleeds over the dive.

This is what my page looks like after i use the jQuery load() on a DIV:

[image: jquery load]

It should look like this when loaded:

[image: jquery load 2]

This is what my HTML DIV code looks like:

```
 <div class="container_1" id="mainHTML">  
  <div class="pageinner" id="innerHTML">
    <p style="font-size: 24px;" class="MMHeader">The CMS System<p>
    <p style="color: #F90;" class="mmBelowHeader">Please provide your email and password below in order to log into the CMS system.<p>
        <section class="main" id="mainContent">
            <div class="form-4">
                <p>
                    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Email Address">
                </p>
                <p>
                    <input type="password" name='password' id="password" placeholder="Password"> 
                </p>

                <p>
                    <button class="orange" name="forgotLoginButton" id="forgotLoginButton" onclick="shrinkBox();" style="margin-right: 5px;">Forgot Password</button>
                    <button class="blue" name="LoginButton" id="LoginButton" onclick="mainMenu();" >Log in</button>
            </div>​
        </section>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mainHTML").animate({width:500, height: 300, overflow: 'auto'});
    $("#innerHTML").animate({width:470, overflow: 'auto'});
    $(".form-4").animate({margin: '10px auto 10px', overflow: 'auto'});
    $('#mainContent').load('test.html');
});
</script>
```

I'm sure its because i am animating the width/height of the box but surly there is a way to keep the loaded content within the DIV and size the height of it according to whats loaded??

**UPDATE**

```
$('#mainContent').fadeOut(0).load('test.html', function() {
    $('#mainHTML').animate({width:940, height: 'auto'});
    $("#innerHTML").animate({width:940, overflow: 'auto'});
}).fadeIn(2000);
```

But it does **not** resize the div to the loaded html content height-wise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to reset the height of the `#mainHTML` after retrieving data:

```
$('#mainContent').load('test.html', function() {
  $("#mainHTML").stop().css({height: 'auto'});
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KzEpL/
http://jsfiddle.net/KzEpL/1/

Comment: Shouldn't that be **.css({height: 'auto'});**?